# Stackoverfflow with Msys2

Tags: c, windows, msys2

I'm under Windows (10, I guess), using Msys2 for development. I'm coding a program where I need a large array, but I can't use dynamic memory. The problem is, this array is too large to fit on the callstack, which produces a stackoverflow.

I tried to change the callstack size with `ulimit -s 100000`. But my program still crash. When I check  with the same command `ulimit -s` I've got the limit I set. But when I check with a small program with [`getrlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit), I've got the default value.

I saw in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447874/3616601) that we can change some of the Msys2 config values with the file `msys.bat`, but i can't find this file.

**My Question**
How can I change the callstack on windows/Msys2?

Comment: Pass a pointer and the size of the array to your function...

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your code? Are you passing an allocated big array (maybe static) or do you want to allocate a big array inside a function?

Comment: I'm passing a static array, declared in the main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the large array by pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

char large_array[100000000];

void myfunc (char *array, size_t size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        //STUFF
}

int main()
{
    myfunc(large_array, sizeof(large_array)/sizeof(large_array[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An explanation stating that this avoids the problem by creating the array in static storage rather than on the stack. (Not my downvote)

Comment: @ikegami Per my understanding, OP has a big array and wants to pass it to a function (_callstack_)...but baybe you are right