# Configure mintty for git-bash / msys2, background color etc

Tags: background-color, git-bash, msys2, mintty

Basically re-asking "[How do you configure Msys's default size, color, and font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447824/)" after 11 years when all the answers are not applicable any more.

So, git-bash / msys2 start under `mintty`. How to configure  `mintty`'s default background color? I want to change it from pure black to a certain grey.

Also, I found that for the `mintty` under msys2, the vertical scrollbar is not working. I.e. I am unable to scroll back at all. Mouse scrolling only scroll the command line, not the window. That's a mis-configuration that I want to fix as well.

**UPDATE**:

So with the icon in the upper left of the MinTTY, I got my color right, but scrollbar was still not working:

[image]

until I got out of `tmux` and realized it was a `tmux` problem.

So all good now.

Comment: Did you click on the icon in the upper left and open the MinTTY Options screen?  Are the options there not working somehow? There are options for colors and whether to have a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGrayson all working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the icon in the upper left of the window and then select "Options" to open the MinTTY Options.   There are options for colors and whether to have a scrollbar.